# Getting highlighted text

Tags: vb.net

I have a text box.  I need to get extract the highlighted and copy that to another text box.
User will highlight it after typing.

How to do it?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`SelectedText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectedtext.aspx) property (also [available in XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectedtext.aspx), if you’re using WPF instead of WinForms):

```
OtherTextBox.Text = FirstTextBox.SelectedText
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about a `System.Windows.Control`, you can grab the [`SelectedText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectedtext%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) on the [`SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionchanged%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) event.